# Verlinkung zu Standardverzeichnissen und Referenzen, gibt es diese überhaupt?

Tags: discussion, reference

In meinen Antworten versuche ich Referenzen zu finden. Allerdings fällt es mir dabei oft schwer zu entscheiden, ob eine Referenz neutral oder vielleicht gar zu kommerziell ist. Am liebsten verweise ich natürliche auf erklärtermaßen quelloffene und freie Verzeichnisse. Aber wie haltet ihr das? Was ist gängige Praxis? Beispiele:

Ich zitiere einen Paragraphen der deutschen Rechtschreibregeln. Soweit ich das sehe gibt es das Original "nur" als PDF. Verschiedene Seiten führen diese Paragraphen einzeln auf, wie z.B. Cannoo. Versucht ihr diese immer zu verlinken?

Im Duden ist ein Wort erklärt, allerdings ist der Duden ein kommerzielles Unternehmen und keine gemeinnützige Organisation, was mich ehrlich gesagt etwas stört. Ich möchte auch keine Monopolisten fördern.

Was ist eure Antwortpraxis? Habt ihr damit auch ein Problem? Ich frage mich, ist es in Ordnung auf fremde Angebote zu verweisen, oder sollte man sparsam sein?

Nachtrag: Vielleicht ist die Frage etwas schwierig und sehr breit, dennoch würde mich sehr eure Meinung interessieren.

Answer (score 2):

Wann immer wir die Meinung oder Erkenntnisse aus einer anderen Quelle als unserer Erinnerung kundtun, ist es guter Stil, diese Quelle auch zu nennen. Dabei ist es nicht unbedingt notwendig und manchmal auch unmöglich, einen direkten Link zu setzen.

Wenn wir aber eine Internetquelle haben, erleichtert es ungemein, wenn man  hier einen direkten Link zur Quelle finden. Nur so können unsere Leser die Güte einer getroffenen Aussage selbst beurteilen. Dann muss ein Link auch nicht unbedint zu einer seriösen Quelle führen, denn [Stupipedia](http://www.stupidedia.org) oder [Der Postillon](http://www.der-postillon.com/) als Quelle wird jeder anders bewerten als eine Aussage die man auf [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org), [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/), [Canoo](http://canoo.net/), oder [Die Zeit](http://www.zeit.de) findet.

Eine Aussage ohne Quellenangabe hat auch immer ein wenig den [Hautgout](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hautgout) einer selbst erfundenen eigenen Meinung, die nicht immer stimmen muss.

<sup>**Hier noch meine persönliche Meinung zu Duden:** Links zu Duden vermeide ich in letzter Zeit, wann immer es geht, da dort leider regelmäßig sehr aggressive Werbung inklusive Pop-Ups geschaltet wird.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Verlinken würde ich nur auf die offizielle Quelle (Das heißt, soweit behandelt, die Seiten des Rechtschreibrats), wenn ich die Wahl habe. Man kann zwar nicht *in* das Dokument verlinken, aber dort gibt's ja schließlich § und Unterabteilungen, die man nennen kann.

Wenn ich sage "wenn ich die Wahl habe" bedeutet das, dass es durchaus Sachverhalte geben kann, in denen Quellen unterschiedlicher Meinung sind. Das betrifft zwar weniger die Rechtschreibregeln, aber Grammatik, Wortbedeutungen und Ethymologie unterliegen durchaus einer gewissen Interpretationsbandbreite. Da ist es oft kein Fehler, mehrere Quellen anzugeben und auch in der Antwort herauszuarbeiten, wo die jeweiligen Unterschiede liegen.

Meine typischen Quellverlinkungen wären Rechtschreibrat, Duden, canoo.net, dict.cc, möglicherweise noch das Grimmsche Wörterbuch bei der Uni Trier, und zwar in dieser Reihenfolge.

Wo man hin verlinkt, sollte schon in irgendeiner Art und Weise eine Referenz darstellen: Andere Quellen ("GuteFrage.net", private Homepages oder andere "Allgemeine Lebenshilfeseiten") halte ich für eher zweifelhaft und würde lieber drauf verzichten - Da steht auch mal viel unbelegter Blödsinn.

Dass der Duden ein kommerzielles Unternehmen ist, stört mich eigentlich nicht, solange er keinen Unsinn schreibt. Google ist auch eins und ist auch ein Monopolist - Verwendest du deren Seiten deshalb nicht?.

Prinzipiell sehe ich es so, dass der Link alleine nicht ausreicht, um hier eine Frage zu beantworten. Andersrum ist das schon der Fall, allgemein anerkannte Tatsachen brauchen keinen Link für eine ordentliche Antwort.

Wenn man verlinkt, sollte man schon ein bißchen zusammenfassend schreiben, was dort steht, solange das vom Umfang her machbar ist (ist es das nicht, ist das allerdings sehr oft ein Fehler der Frage, die zu breit angelegt ist, als ein Fehler der Antwort). Der Link selbst dient dann nur dem Beleg und möglicherweise auch der weiteren Eigenrecherche des Fragers. Die eigentliche Frage sollte aber schon hier im Text beantwortet sein und nicht erst am anderen Ende eines Links.

Comment: Anderes Beispiel: Stack Exchange ist ein kommerzielles Unternehmen und hat ein Monopol was Programmier-Q&A-Seiten betrifft.

Answer (score 1):

Der Duden war jahrelang das offizielle Verzeichnis der bundesdeutschen Rechtschreibung. Inwiefern er Gültigkeit in Österreich und Südtirol, der Schweiz und Liechtenstein, Ostbelgien, Süddänemark und Luxemburg hat(te), entzieht sich meiner Kenntnis. (Abgesehen davon, dass Hubert öfters auf das Österreichische Wörterbuch ÖWB hingewiesen hat, von dem ich ausgehe, dass es in Österreich und ggf. Südtirol die Stellung des Dudens hatte.)

Der Duden ist seit der Rechtschreibreform nicht mehr maßgeblich. Gleichzeitig ersetzt ihn das Wörterverzeichnis des Rechtschreibrates nicht, da es explizit nur (selbst ausgewählte) Zweifelsfälle verzeichnet. Große Teile der in Deutschland gültigen Rechtschreibung muss man also als ungeregelt ansehen. Dennoch genießt der Duden in großen Teilen der Bevölkerung weiterhin den sehr hohen Status eines (ehemals) offiziellen Nachschlagewerkes – ich meine, dass sich die Scrabble-Regeln zum Beispiel explizit auf den Duden und nichts anderes beziehen.

Ja, der Duden ist ein *de facto* Monopolist, und ja, es handelt sich um ein gewinnorientiertes Unternehmen. Gleiches kann aber auch über die Deutsche Post gesagt werden. Verschickst du deswegen keine Briefe, wo es der Schriftform bedarf, sondern wirfst selber ein? Es ist auch ganz gut, dass es maximal ein offizielles Verzeichnis gibt – selbst in diesem gibt es schon zu viele Varianten als gut für manche Lernende oder Schreibende wäre. In diesem Sinne hoffe ich, dass sich keine Konkurrenzsituation auftut, in der zum Beispiel entweder die Duden- oder die Wahrig-Schreibweise gewählt werden kann.

---

Nun zu meiner Antwortpraxis, die ich auch so von anderen gesehen habe. Dort, wo man die offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln zitiert, sollte man auch auf das offizielle PDF verlinken. Zusätzlich sollte man den Paragraphen angeben, mit dem man sich leicht im Dokument zurechtfinden kann. Gleiches gilt für welche Quelle auch immer derzeit das offizielle Wörterverzeichnis führt. Für Benutzer aus Österreich, Fragen zum Sprachgebrauch dort oder vergleichbares darf es auch gerne das ÖWB sein; dito für weitere nichtbundesdeutsche offizielle Quellen.

Darüberhinaus ist es dir freigestellt, jederzeit auch andere Quellen zu verlinken, wenn du diese brauchst, um deine Antwort zu belegen. Ich finde zum Beispiel die Grammatikerklärungen auf Canoo.net sowie das DWDS sehr gut und verlinke sie ab und an; bei Letzterem gerne auch direkt die dort verwendeten Quellen des DWB oder des etymologischen Wörterbuchs.

Mir ist es wichtiger, dass das, was in der Quelle steht, korrekt ist, als ob die Quelle nun frei (im Sinne freier Software) oder kommerziell ist. Da ich einige unschöne Erfahrungen mit dict.cc gemacht habe (dafür aber überwiegend gute mit Leo) verlinke ich es eher ungern (Leo dagegen eher gerne). Wenn es um den Gebrauch  einer bestimmten Wendung etc. geht, kann sowieso jede *x*-beliebige Seite herhalten. Vor den üblichen Problem der Verlinkung im Internet ist keine dieser Quellen gefeit.

Comment: *Ich bin mir nicht völlig sicher, ob das Wörterverzeichnis des Rechtschreibrates inzwischen den Duden als offizielles Verzeichnis abgelöst hat.* – Das Wörterverzeichnis des Rechtschreibrats dient dazu Klarheit bei rechtschreiblich schwierigen Wörtern zu schaffen (und ist somit für Scrabble völlig ungeeignet, da sich z. B. das Wort *geeignet* darin nicht findet). Der Duden hingegen strebt an, alle Wörter zu erfassen, die tatsächlich im Gebrauch sind. Damit dokumentiert er nicht nur die Rechtschreibung, sondern auch die Verwendung.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Aha. Das heißt, das Wörterverzeichnis dient nur für einige, ausgewählte Zweifelsfälle und der Rest ist *de facto* ungeregelt? Oder zählt der Duden weiterhin als offizielle Quelle, solange er dem Verzeichnis nicht widerspricht?

Comment: Ersteres. Der Duden hat jeglichen offiziellen Rang mit der Rechtschreibreform verloren.

Answer (score 1):

Bei online verfügbaren Quellen halte ich es im Allgemeinen so:

1. offizielle Quelle
2. öffentlich/kostenfrei zugängliche Quelle

   1. [freier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freie_Inhalte) Inhalt, ohne Werbung
   2. freier Inhalt, mit Werbung
   3. unfreier Inhalt, ohne Werbung
   4. unfreier Inhalt, mit Werbung
3. zugriffsgeschützte/kostenpflichtige Quelle

   1. freier Inhalt, ohne Werbung
   2. freier Inhalt, mit Werbung
   3. unfreier Inhalt, ohne Werbung
   4. unfreier Inhalt, mit Werbung

Für German Language SE wären es also bevorzugt Links zu den PDFs von [rechtschreibrat.com](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/) gefolgt von Links zu den Webseiten von [de.wiktionary.org](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Hauptseite).

**Wiktionary** wird von der gemeinnützigen Wikimedia-Foundation betrieben (wie Wikipedia). Die Inhalte stehen unter der gleichen [freien Lizenz](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) wie die Inhalte hier bei German Language SE. Die Inhalte können, wie bei Stack Exchange auch, von Nutzern editiert werden und es ist möglich, eine bestimmte Revision zu verlinken ([Beispiel](https://de.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Hummel&oldid=5983963)). Und alles ist öffentlich zugänglich und werbefrei.