# Zitieren aus Wörterbüchern/Lexika (und das Urheberrecht)

Tags: discussion

Wenn wir bei Antworten aus Duden/Kluge/ÖWB etc. zitieren, dürfen wir dabei den Text zu einem Eintrag unverändert kopieren, oder müssen wir dasselbe in eigenen Worten sagen?

Z.B. weiß ich nicht, ob ich bei [dieser Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/50702/15277), die nur kryptisch auf den Vornamen-Duden referiert, vorbehaltlos empfehlen darf, einfach den relevanten Eintrag abzutippen.

Answer (score 5):

#### TL;DR: Zitate ja, aber bitte mit Quellenangabe

---

Das ist eine nicht ganz einfache, aber wichtige Frage, auf die wir leider keine einfache Antwort geben können. Dazu wäre wohl eine ganze Rechtsabteilung mit mehreren Rechtsanwälten nötig. Wir Moderatoren sind alle keine Anwälte, so dass wir nur eine Richtung vorgeben können. Zu beachten ist, dass auch German Language eine **US-amerikanische** Seite ist, die nur der Rechtssprechung der USA verpflichtet ist.

Es gibt eine Reihe von Beiträgen zu diesem Thema, hier nur Beispiele:

- [Dealing with posts plagiarising from copyrighted sources](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19508/dealing-with-posts-plagiarising-from-copyrighted-sources)
- [How does SOPA threaten Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114005/how-does-sopa-threaten-stack-overflow-stack-exchange)
- [EU copyright laws (2018-2019). Any risk for Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311073/eu-copyright-laws-2018-2019-any-risk-for-stack-exchange)
- [Worauf ist bei der Wiedergabe von Zitaten in Texten zu achten?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/611/worauf-ist-bei-der-wiedergabe-von-zitaten-in-texten-zu-achten)
- [Verlinkung zu Standardverzeichnissen und Referenzen, gibt es diese überhaupt?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1281/verlinkung-zu-standardverzeichnissen-und-referenzen-gibt-es-diese-%c3%bcberhaupt)

Der Gundtenor ist, wen wundert es, dass das Internet ohne Zitate und Verweise ein unnützer und lebloser Raum wäre. Wir benötigen also Inhalte, auch wenn sie andere generiert haben. Das EU-Recht kennt den Begriff [*fair use*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) so nicht, wie er in den USA erlaubtes Zitieren beschreibt. Dennoch wird man, solange man seine Quellen nennt, sich darauf berufen und stillschweigen annehmen, dass es OK ist.

Solange niemand die Firma Stack Exchange verklagt und um Löschung von zweifelhaftem Inhalt bittet, kann man getrost wörtliche Zitate einfügen. Im Zweifel kann man den Urheber ja fragen, bevor man seinen Post absetzt.

Was meiner Meinung aber gar nicht geht, ist, sich mit fremden Federn zu schmücken und die Arbeit anderer als seine eigene darzustellen. Hier wurden wir Moderatoren auch schon in der Vegangenheit aktiv. Eine sorgfältige Quellenangabe brauchen wir (das sind wir alle hier) schon, auch um den Wahrheitsgehalt einer Aussage besser abschätzzen zu können.

Answer (score 3):

Die neue Urheberrechtsrichtlinie der EU in der beschlossenen Fassung findet auf uns fast keine Anwendung. Sie enthält zwar den hoch umstrittenen Artikel 17 (Artikel 13 in der Vorlage; durch Ergänzungen, Streichungen und Umsortierungen mit einer neuen Nummer versehen), der »Online content-sharing service providers« (laut der englischen Fassung) behandelt; man könnte argumentieren, dass Stack Exchange ein solcher Anbieter sei. Die Richtlinie behandelt aber das Hochladen kompletter Werke, und interessant ist der Artikel 17, Absatz 7 Unterpunkt a:

> 7. […]
>
>    Member States shall ensure that users in each Member State are able to rely on
>      any of the following existing exceptions or limitations when uploading and making
>      available content generated by users on online content-sharing services:
>
>    (a) quotation, criticism, review;
>
> (Quelle: [Verordnungstext auf Englisch auf den Seiten des Europaparlaments](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/A-8-2018-0245-AM-271-271_EN.pdf))

Es gelten also weiterhin die bisher vorhandenen Regelungen zu Zitaten und es soll, sobald die Regelung in Kraft tritt, explizit die Zitatmöglichkeit eröffnet bleiben.

Das führt uns zur nächsten Frage, dem (deutschen) Zitatrecht, das im Urheberrechtsgesetz (UrhG) geregelt ist. Dort heißt es in § 51:

> Zulässig ist die Vervielfältigung, Verbreitung und öffentliche Wiedergabe eines veröffentlichten Werkes zum Zweck des Zitats, sofern die Nutzung in ihrem Umfang durch den besonderen Zweck gerechtfertigt ist. Zulässig ist dies insbesondere, wenn
>
> 1. einzelne Werke nach der Veröffentlichung in ein selbständiges wissenschaftliches Werk zur Erläuterung des Inhalts aufgenommen werden,
> 2. Stellen eines Werkes nach der Veröffentlichung in einem selbständigen Sprachwerk angeführt werden,
> 3. einzelne Stellen eines erschienenen Werkes der Musik in einem selbständigen Werk der Musik angeführt werden.
>
> Von der Zitierbefugnis gemäß den Sätzen 1 und 2 umfasst ist die Nutzung einer Abbildung oder sonstigen Vervielfältigung des zitierten Werkes, auch wenn diese selbst durch ein Urheberrecht oder ein verwandtes Schutzrecht geschützt ist.
>
> (Quelle: [Volltext des Urheberrechtsgesetzes (UrhG) auf `gesetze-im-internet.de`](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/urhg/BJNR012730965.html))

Die Nutzung von Auszügen aus dem Online-Duden oder anderen Seiten zur Begründung der Aussage, als Beispiel oder aus anderen Gründen ist also zulässig, *wenn* die fertige Antwort ein selbstständiges Werk wird. Auf Stack Exchange bedeutet das insbesondere, dass Antworten die ausschließlich aus Zitaten (gekennzeichnet oder nicht) bestehen, nach deutschem Urheberrecht unzulässig sind – und deswegen als kopierte Antwort gelöscht werden.

Neben dem § 51 sind auch die §§ 62 und 63 für das Zitatrecht relevant. Vorweg: Sie alle stehen im gleichen Abschnitt 6 aber in verschiedenen Unterabschnitten.

> **§ 62 Änderungsverbot**
>
> 1. Soweit nach den Bestimmungen dieses Abschnitts die Benutzung eines Werkes zulässig ist, dürfen Änderungen an dem Werk nicht vorgenommen werden. § 39 gilt entsprechend.
> 2. Soweit der Benutzungszweck es erfordert, sind Übersetzungen und solche Änderungen des Werkes zulässig, die nur Auszüge oder Übertragungen in eine andere Tonart oder Stimmlage darstellen.
> 3. Bei Werken der bildenden Künste und Lichtbildwerken sind Übertragungen des Werkes in eine andere Größe und solche Änderungen zulässig, die das für die Vervielfältigung angewendete Verfahren mit sich bringt.
> 4. […]
> 5. […]
>
> **§ 63 Quellenangabe**
>
> 1. Wenn ein Werk oder ein Teil eines Werkes in den Fällen des § 45 Abs. 1, der §§ 45a bis 48, 50, **51**, 58, 59 sowie der §§ 60a bis 60d, 61 und 61c vervielfältigt oder verbreitet wird, ist stets die Quelle deutlich anzugeben. Bei der Vervielfältigung oder Verbreitung ganzer Sprachwerke oder ganzer Werke der Musik ist neben dem Urheber auch der Verlag anzugeben, in dem das Werk erschienen ist, und außerdem kenntlich zu machen, ob an dem Werk Kürzungen oder andere Änderungen vorgenommen worden sind. Die Verpflichtung zur Quellenangabe entfällt, wenn die Quelle weder auf dem benutzten Werkstück oder bei der benutzten Werkwiedergabe genannt noch dem zur Vervielfältigung oder Verbreitung Befugten anderweit bekannt ist oder im Fall des § 60a oder des § 60b Prüfungszwecke einen Verzicht auf die Quellenangabe erfordern.
> 2. Soweit nach den Bestimmungen dieses Abschnitts die öffentliche Wiedergabe eines Werkes zulässig ist, ist die Quelle deutlich anzugeben, wenn und soweit die Verkehrssitte es erfordert. In den Fällen der öffentlichen Wiedergabe nach den §§ 46, 48, **51**, 60a bis 60d, 61 und 61c ist die Quelle einschließlich des Namens des Urhebers stets anzugeben, es sei denn, dass dies nicht möglich ist.
> 3. Wird ein Artikel aus einer Zeitung oder einem anderen Informationsblatt nach § 49 Abs. 1 in einer anderen Zeitung oder in einem anderen Informationsblatt abgedruckt oder durch Funk gesendet, so ist stets außer dem Urheber, der in der benutzten Quelle bezeichnet ist, auch die Zeitung oder das Informationsblatt anzugeben, woraus der Artikel entnommen ist; ist dort eine andere Zeitung oder ein anderes Informationsblatt als Quelle angeführt, so ist diese Zeitung oder dieses Informationsblatt anzugeben. Wird ein Rundfunkkommentar nach § 49 Abs. 1 in einer Zeitung oder einem anderen Informationsblatt abgedruckt oder durch Funk gesendet, so ist stets außer dem Urheber auch das Sendeunternehmen anzugeben, das den Kommentar gesendet hat.
>
> (Quelle: [Volltext des Urheberrechtsgesetzes (UrhG) auf `gesetze-im-internet.de`](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/urhg/BJNR012730965.html); Hervorhebungen der 51 durch mich).

Daraus ergeben sich in deutschem Recht folgende Folgerungen:

- Wir *dürfen* einzelne, kurze Stücke kopieren und wortgleich hier in einer Antwort schreiben – und wir *müssen* sogar das Zitat unverändert lassen (wobei Kürzungen erlaubt sind; sie sollten den Sinn aber nicht entstellen).
- Wir *müssen* die Quelle stets angeben, wobei im Internet in der Regel ein Link auf den Originaltext (beim Originalautor oder in einer urheberrechtlich unbedenklichen Fassung!) ausreicht; wer ganz auf Nummer sicher gehen will, gibt auch den Autor des Originals an (im Falle des Dudens wäre das wahrscheinlich der Duden-Verlag).
- Wir *müssen* das Zitat von eigenem Material umgeben; das heißt, ihm Kontext mitgeben, es für unsere Argumente oder Thesen verwenden. Das bloße Zitieren reicht *nicht* aus.

---

Wie Takkat in seiner Antwort schon erwähnt hat, gilt im Zweifel für Stack Exchange aber eher das amerikanische Recht. Auch dieses kennt Zitate, das Änderungsverbot und das Quellengebot. In groben Zügen sollte also die gleiche Antwort entstehen, selbst wenn von den amerikanischen Rechtsvorschriften ausgegangen wird.

Comment: Ordentliches Arbeiten ist also weiterhin nach EU/deutschem Recht erlaubt und das legerere amerikanische Recht sollte noch weniger Probleme bereiten. Nice. Was fehlt ist jedoch: Wir *müssen* diese Linie halten. Und wenn EU-Kommissare oder sonstwer wieder Ideen hat, diese verteidigen, besser noch beständig ausbauen!